# I am relatively new to Python, and I am trying to use classes and methods to find the card given the rank and suit

Tags: python-2.7

I am required to find the rank and suit of a card using **str** method  I am not sure that I am doing this correctly.  I get the correct answer in main, but it does not print out the statement that I would like it from the method **str**.   What am I missing?

```
from math import *
from random import *
from string import * 

class Card:

    def __init__(self, rank, suit) :
        self.rank = int(rank)
        self.suit = str(suit) 

    def getRank(self) :
        return self.rank

    def getSuit(self):  
        return self.suit

    def __str__(self): 

        if self.rank == 1:
            if self.suit == "d" :
                print "The card is an Ace of Diamonds "
            elif self.suit == "c":
                print "The card is an Ace of Clubs"
            elif self.suit == "h" :
                print "The card is an Ace of Hearts"
            elif self.suit == "s" :
                print "The card is an Ace of Spades"

        elif self.rank in range(2, 11):
            if self.suit == "d" :
                print "The card is a", rank,  "of Diamonds"
            elif self.suit == "c" :
                print "The card is a", rank,  "of Clubs"            
            elif self.suit == "h" :
                print "The card is a", rank,  "of Hearts"
            elif self.suit == "s" :
                print "The card is a", rank,  "of Spades"

        elif self.rank == 11 :
            if self.suit == "d" :
                print "The card is a Jack of Diamonds"
            elif self.suit == "c" :
                print "The card is a Jack of Clubs"            
            elif self.suit == "h" :
                print "The card is a Jack of Hearts"
            elif self.suit == "s" :
                print "The card is a Jack of Spades"

        elif self.rank == 12 :
            if self.suit == "d" :
                print "The card is a Queen of Diamonds"
            elif self.suit == "c" :
                print "The card is a Queen of Clubs"            
            elif self.suit == "h" :
                print "The card is a Queen of Hearts"
            elif self.suit == "s" :
                print "The card is a Queen of Spades"

        elif self.rank == 13 :
            if self.suit == "d" :
                print "The card is a King of Diamonds"
            elif self.suit == "c" :
                print "The card is a King of Clubs"            
            elif self.suit == "h" :
                print "The card is a King of Hearts"
            elif self.suit == "s" :
                print "The card is a King of Spades"

        return self.rank, self.suit 

def main():

    #  You can also pick the cards at random using randrange() function 

    x = raw_input("Enter the rank and suit for the card that you picked (tab separated) ")
    print x 

    rank, suit = x.split("\t")
    print rank, suit 

    s = Card(int(rank), str(suit))

    print s.getRank(), s.getSuit(), s.__str__()

    if __name__ == '__main__' :
        main()
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you included code outside of code blocks that made it a bit confusing for me to piece together.

As far as your code, the print statement is working for me. If you want the print statement in the method str to work, you need to call it.

Currently this is what your function is returning to me:

```
3 h
3 h The card is a 3 of Hearts 
(3, 'h')
```

The first "3 h" is coming from your

```
print rank, suit
```

that comes just after your input.

the 3 h The card is a 3 of Hearts comes from calling

```
s.getRank() ## Returns 3
s.getSuit() ## Returns h
s.__str__()  ##Returns:
#The card is a 3 of Hearts 
#(3, 'h')
```

This last s.**str**() returns multiple parts because of your return statement in conjunction with print statements. I am not sure the format you want your code to return in, but I would think you just want the s.**str**() to return "The card is a 3 of Hearts"

Currently it returns

```
self.rank, self.suit
```

but those are already returned by that class so I am not sure why they are there. You could make it only return your print statement.

```
class Card:

    def __init__(self, rank, suit) :
        self.rank = int(rank)
        self.suit = str(suit) 

    def getRank(self) :
        return self.rank

    def getSuit(self):  
        return self.suit

    def __str__(self): 

        if self.rank == 1:
            if self.suit == "d" :
                printstatement= "The card is an Ace of Diamonds "
            elif self.suit == "c":
                printstatement=  "The card is an Ace of Clubs"
            elif self.suit == "h" :
                printstatement=  "The card is an Ace of Hearts"
            elif self.suit == "s" :
                printstatement=  "The card is an Ace of Spades"

        elif self.rank in range(2, 11):
            if self.suit == "d" :
                printstatement=  "The card is a "+ rank +" of Diamonds"
            elif self.suit == "c" :
                printstatement=  "The card is a "+ rank +" of Clubs"            
            elif self.suit == "h" :
                printstatement=  "The card is a "+ rank +" of Hearts"
            elif self.suit == "s" :
                printstatement=  "The card is a "+ rank +" of Spades"

        elif self.rank == 11 :
            if self.suit == "d" :
                printstatement=  "The card is a Jack of Diamonds"
            elif self.suit == "c" :
                printstatement=  "The card is a Jack of Clubs"            
            elif self.suit == "h" :
                printstatement=  "The card is a Jack of Hearts"
            elif self.suit == "s" :
                printstatement=  "The card is a Jack of Spades"

        elif self.rank == 12 :
            if self.suit == "d" :
                printstatement=  "The card is a Queen of Diamonds"
            elif self.suit == "c" :
                printstatement=  "The card is a Queen of Clubs"            
            elif self.suit == "h" :
                printstatement=  "The card is a Queen of Hearts"
            elif self.suit == "s" :
                printstatement=  "The card is a Queen of Spades"

        elif self.rank == 13 :
            if self.suit == "d" :
                printstatement=  "The card is a King of Diamonds"
            elif self.suit == "c" :
                printstatement=  "The card is a King of Clubs"            
            elif self.suit == "h" :
                printstatement=  "The card is a King of Hearts"
            elif self.suit == "s" :
                printstatement=  "The card is a King of Spades"

        return str(printstatement)
```

If you change your class to reflect the code posted immediately above, your code outputs this:

```
7 h
7 h The card is a 7 of Hearts
```

If you want the final string to be on its own line, you can do this:

```
## Change this:
print s.getRank(), s.getSuit(), s.__str__()  
## To this:
print s.getRank(), s.getSuit(), "\n", s.__str__()
## To have your code output this:
4 d
4 d 
The card is a 4 of Diamonds
```

Comment: Sorry It took me so long to get back.  I did not realize that you had responded promptly, but I had somehow failed to see your response. I think what I needed was the output "the card was a 'rank' of 'suit' which I did not seem to get. But I think what helps is the statement to return statement in the str method.  I had added the extra print statements to try to figure out where the error was.

Comment: So you are still not getting an output of "The card is a 4 of Diamonds" when you run your code? With the changes I mentioned above that is what the program is outputting for me. You would just have to change the is to was.